Why can't I add implementations in Android Studio Iguana?
I have just downloaded the latest version of Android Studio, the Iguana - 2023.2.1, but when I open my build.gradle(:app), it shows like this. 
It doesn't look like the implementation I am going to add in there. (my implementation: implementation 'android.database.sqlite.3.42.0')
Can you help me? I'm new to Android Studio and I'd love to know more things!

The way of implementing dependencies has been changed. You have to specify the versions/ libraries/ plugins in the libs.versions.toml file Situated inside Gradle Script Directory.

Gradle version catalogs enable you to add and maintain dependencies and plugins in a scalable way.

To know more about the .toml and how to implement/ migrate click here.
